# detailed error log with asynchronous mocha tests

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have this asynchronous mocha test, where I return an error object to indicate an error:

```
describe "error object", →
  it "should fail", (done) →
    done(new Error({link: "mock" }))
```

This is the output:

```
1) error object should fail:
Error: [object Object]
```

I expect to see the details:

```
1) error object should fail:
Error: { link: "mock" }
```

How can I see the detailed error output in mocha tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
describe "error object",
  it "should fail", (done)
    done(new Error(JSON.stringify({link: "mock" })));
```